# Uniform arrays or Textures for passing data to fragment shaders?

Tags: textures, webgl, fragment-shader

If you have a lot of floating point data to pass to a fragment shader, is it a better idea to use uniform arrays or textures? It seems like uniform arrays are the proper way to do it, but the array size seems limited (especially in WebGL, which is where I'm working) If I want to send information about thousands of objects (for the purposes of raytracing) is there any realistic alternative to using textures for passing data? Is this a bad thing or a good thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Textures are the way to go for huge amounts of floating point data.

If at all possible, pack the data into 4-component vectors and remove as many branching instructions as you can from your fragment shader.  The idea is to perform as little logic as possible on the GPU and boil your shaders down to a few operations that need to be performed on a huge amount of data.

Programming massively parallel hardware is totally different than coding for a CPU, and a lot of the standard intuition about performance is completely opposite in a parallel environment.  A good place to start is here:

http://developer.download.nvidia.com/GPU_Programming_Guide/GPU_Programming_Guide.pdf